# Multi-Line Rscript in Dockerfile

Tags: r, bash, docker, rscript

I am trying to build a docker image with R, and I'd like to be able to break out my package install steps in a clean, easy to read, manner across multiple lines, but bash does not seem to like the approach due to not knowing where the ending ) is.

Is there a way to make this long line of code split across multiple lines?

```
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_cran(c("tidytext","janitor","corrr","officer","devtools","pacman"))'
```

To maybe, something like this:

```
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_cran(c("tidytext","janitor",
                              "corrr","officer","devtools","pacman"))'
```

Is this possible to do with Rscript? I have tried using a \ at the end of each line, and it still does not work.

I understand install2.r can list out the packages line by line, but I would like to have a vector of packages to pass to `devtools::install_cran` if possible. I have seen others simply refer to their R script by simply calling it via Rscript, but I would like to see all my installation steps inside my Dockerfile, and not copy and run an external R script in my container. Thanks for your help.

```
Rscript test.R
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BASH will interpret a newline as the end of the command.

In BASH (which I'm assuming you're using), a backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as a continuation of the line. Except when it is inside single quotes!

So...

```
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_cran(c("tidytext","janitor",
                          "corrr","officer","devtools","pacman"))'
```

will be interpreted as two commands...

```
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_cran(c("tidytext","janitor",
```

and

```
"corrr","officer","devtools","pacman"))'
```

Neither of which are well formed.

Additionally, single quoted strings in BASH will not handle escapes.  They simply assume your text is literal.  So you cannot continue a line within single quoted strings in BASH.

The bottom line is that if you want continuation within a quoted string in BASH, you must use double quoted strings.  Your options are as follows:

```
Rscript -e "devtools::install_cran(c('tidytext','janitor', \  
                'corrr','officer','devtools','pacman'))"
```

using double quotes in BASH and single quotes in R or...

```
Rscript -e "devtools::install_cran(c(\"tidytext\",\"janitor\", \    
                \"corrr\",\"officer\",\"devtools\",\"pacman\"))"
```

using double quotes in both.

Comment: Ahh, very helpful, thank you. Is there any places I can go for more information on this?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html would probably be sufficient for this.  Specifically the https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting section.

Comment: Edited the post to indicate that \ + endline will be ignored within single quotes.

Comment: _"Is there any places I can go for more information on this? "_  Every shell programing resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few reference Docker files you could look at. Here is a part from one of ours from the [Rocker Project](https://rocker-project.org) producing the official r-base image:

```
RUN apt-get update \     
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \     
                ed \                                 
                less \   
                locales \     
                vim-tiny \   
                wget \  
                ca-certificates \
                fonts-texgyre \ 
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Now this is for `apt` packages but R packages from CRAN work in the same way: one long line, broken up by backslashes. We tend to use `install.r` or `install2.r` from [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) for this. So your code would become

```
install.r tidytext \
   janitor \
   corrr \
   officer \
   devtools \
   pacman
```

An under-appreciated aspect is that you *can* in fact get some of these as binaries from either Debian or Ubuntu, but I leave the legwork of finding this out for yourself.